# Connect an azure database to existing xamarin project

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.forms

I am having trouble connecting my Azure database to an existing Xamarin forms project. I have followed all the steps to make the database accessible but don't understand how to connect it to the project.

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: The fact that your client is a Xamarin.Forms application should not affect your ability to connect to an Azure database any more than if you had a console application or a ASP.Net Web application. Also, please provide the code that attempts to connect and any exceptions you run into otherwise we cannot answer properly.

Comment: hi @m-y thanks for your response. I haven't coded anything yet as I am new to this and unsure what to do. I am currently using the quickstart option on azure and trying to link it to an existing project.

Comment: You typically use a middle tier to connect your app to a database.  One way is to use Azure Mobile App Service https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/services/app-service/mobile/

Comment: i am having the same problem, it is horribly difficult. 100% of all documentation I've seen is outdated (Microsoft has been removing or changing services that were super great) or incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As CSharpRocks mentioned that Azure Mobile App would be an ideal approach for you to build your mobile backend with  Azure sql database, then you could leverage the client SDK for Azure Mobile Apps in your Xamarin.Forms project to communicate with your Azure sql database.

You could follow the steps below for getting started with Azure Mobile Apps with Xamarin.Forms app:

- Create your Mobile App and configure the server project, for more details you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started#create-a-new-mobile-apps-back-end).

  **Note:** For Node.js backend, you could navigate to "Mobile > Easy tables" for adding new or existing tables, then it would automatically create the Node.js backend (table API) for your added table(s). For C# backend, you could download the sample server project from quickstart or create the Azure Mobile App template via VS and implement table controllers for each of your tables, for more details you could refer to adrian hall's book about [Implementing Table Controllers](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/server/).
- For your mobile client, you could download and run the Xamarin.Forms project from quickstart to getting started with client SDK for Azure Mobile Apps. Also, you could refer to adrian hall's book about [Chapter 3 - Data Access and Offline Sync > The Mobile Client](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/client/).

Additionally, you could add authentication to your Xamarin.Forms app and only the authenticated and authorized users could access the table data under your Mobile App. For more details, you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-users).

Comment: Thank you! brilliant answer Bruce!